# Implementing jQuery's shake effect with animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I've been given a cut down subset of the jQuery lib one of the key features I'm missing is the `.effect` functions. I do however have `.animate`. I was wondering if anyone would have any ideas how I could go about reproducing the animation functions.

I am particularly consious of making this only a few lines as I need to keep the code size down. Which is why the jquery lib is as small as it is and doesnt have the effects functions.

TLDR - I'm trying to replace

```
 $("#"+id_string).effect( "shake", {}, "fast" );
```

With something using `.animate` within jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually already implemented this way under the covers, you can see exactly how in [`jquery.effects.shake.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/0c860b0d92f9959f6747f8c02e9671eb2fc561aa/ui/effects/effect-shake.js), if you wanted to copy only that functionality you can.

Another approach to think about: if you're using multiple effects, I'd recommend [downloading jQuery UI with only the effects you want](http://jqueryui.com/download).  For this effect, without copying the functionality yourself, you would just need [`jquery.effects.core.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/0c860b0d92f9959f6747f8c02e9671eb2fc561aa/ui/effect.js) and [`jquery.effects.shake.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/0c860b0d92f9959f6747f8c02e9671eb2fc561aa/ui/effects/effect-shake.js).

Comment: As I'm stuck in a severly cut down version of jquery I dont have access to the effects code at all. I had been playing with the following .. have to add it as answer as cant seem to format in replies.

Comment: @wmitchell - I linked you to the source code in the answer :)

Comment: New links: [jquery.ui.effect.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect.js) and [jquery.ui.effect.shake.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.effect-shake.js)

Comment: New links again: [effect.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effect.js) and [effect-shake.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effect-shake.js)

Comment: or http://codingstuffsbykiran.blogspot.com/2014/06/jquery-shake-effect-part-2.html

Comment: new links again [effect.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399005/implementing-jquerys-shake-effect-with-animate)  and  [effect-shake.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effects/effect-shake.js)

Comment: New links again: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effect.js and https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/effects/effect-shake.js

Answer (score 45):

So far I have something like this ..

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function(intShakes, intDistance, intDuration) {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).css("position","relative"); 
        for (var x=1; x<=intShakes; x++) {
        $(this).animate({left:(intDistance*-1)}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)))
    .animate({left:intDistance}, ((intDuration/intShakes)/2))
    .animate({left:0}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)));
    }
  });
return this;
};
```

Comment: All those parens... `(((`... why?

Comment: could someone create a fiddle of this?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas he is controlling the order of operations with those `(((`s

Comment: @Fresheyeball Most of those parens are not needed, that was my point. For instance, this - `(((intDuration/intShakes)/4))` - can be replaced with this - `intDuration/intShakes/4` - without changing the order of operations. Also, note the double-wrap - `((expression))` - which serves no purpose.

Comment: This only lets you shake things that don't have left: set to something other than 0.

Answer (score 16):

I like @phpslightly solution so much, I keep using it. So here it is updated to basic jquery plugin form which will return your element

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function(interval,distance,times){
   interval = typeof interval == "undefined" ? 100 : interval;
   distance = typeof distance == "undefined" ? 10 : distance;
   times = typeof times == "undefined" ? 3 : times;
   var jTarget = $(this);
   jTarget.css('position','relative');
   for(var iter=0;iter<(times+1);iter++){
      jTarget.animate({ left: ((iter%2==0 ? distance : distance*-1))}, interval);
   }
   return jTarget.animate({ left: 0},interval);
}
```

You would then use it like a regular plugin:

```
$("#your-element").shake(100,10,3);
```

Or use the default values (100, 10, 3):

```
$("#your-element").shake();
```

Comment: Why not just put default value in the param like so ?

`function (interval = 100, distance = 10, times = 1){`

Answer (score 6):

This is probably irrelevant now but I've ported jQ UI's shake effect as a standalone jQuery plugin. All you need is jQuery and it will work exactly like the one provided in jQ UI.

For those who want to use the effect without actually bloating their project with unnecessary jQ UI core files.

`$('#element').shake({...});`

It can be found here with instruction: https://github.com/ninty9notout/jquery-shake

Thought I'd leave this here for future reference.

Answer (score 4):

This is a more clean and smooth way to do the animation.

```js
jQuery.fn.shake = function(shakes, distance, duration) {
    if(shakes > 0) {
        this.each(function() {
            var $el = $(this);
            var left = $el.css('left');
            $el.animate({left: "-=" + distance}, duration, function(){
                $el.animate({left: "+=" + distance * 2}, duration, function() {
                    $el.animate({left: left}, duration, function() {
                        $el.shake(shakes-1, distance, duration); });});
            });
        });
    }
    return this;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand all the complexity being thrown into reproducing the shake effect with solely `animate`. Here's my solution in just a couple lines.

```
function shake(div,interval=100,distance=10,times=4){
    $(div).css('position','relative');
    for(var iter=0;iter<(times+1);iter++){
        $(div).animate({ left: ((iter%2==0 ? distance : distance*-1))}, interval);
    }//for
    $(div).animate({ left: 0},interval);
}//shake
```

EDIT: Updated code to return element to original position. Still believe this is the lightest and best solution to the problem.

Comment: This solution doesn't return the element to its original position after the animation.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some time ago a few simple jquery animations:

https://github.com/yckart/jquery-custom-animations

```
/**
 * @param {number} times - The number of shakes
 * @param {number} duration - The speed amount
 * @param {string} easing - The easing method
 * @param {function} complete - A callback function
 */
jQuery.fn.shake =
jQuery.fn.wiggle = function (times, duration, easing, complete) {
    var self = this;

    if (times > 0) {
        this.animate({
            marginLeft: times-- % 2 === 0 ? -15 : 15
        }, duration, easing, function () {
            self.wiggle(times, duration, easing, complete);
        });
    } else {
        this.animate({
            marginLeft: 0
        }, duration, easing, function () {
            if (jQuery.isFunction(complete)) {
                complete();
            }
        });
    }
    return this;
};
```

Comment: you may also try this http://codingstuffsbykiran.blogspot.com/2014/06/jquery-shake-effect-part-2.html

Answer (score 0):

This is not perfect, but functional

```
    // Example: $('#<% =ButtonTest.ClientID %>').myshake(3, 120, 3, false);
    jQuery.fn.myshake = function (steps, duration, amount, vertical) {
        var s = steps || 3;
        var d = duration || 120;
        var a = amount || 3;
        var v = vertical || false;
        this.css('position', 'relative');
        var cur = parseInt(this.css(v ? "top" : "left"), 10);
        if (isNaN(cur))
            cur = 0;

        var ds = d / s;

        if (v) {
            for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
                this.animate({ "top": cur + a + "px" }, ds).animate({ "top": cur - a + "px" }, ds);
            this.animate({ "top": cur }, 20);
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
                this.animate({ "left": cur + a }, ds).animate({ "left": cur - a + "px" }, ds);
            this.animate({ "left": cur }, 20);
        }

        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @el producer solution, I added some multiply logic and make it look like a random shake.

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function (interval, distance, times) {
    interval = typeof interval == "undefined" ? 100 : interval;
    distance = typeof distance == "undefined" ? 10 : distance;
    times = typeof times == "undefined" ? 3 : times;
    var jTarget = $(this);
    jTarget.css('position', 'relative');
    for (var iter = 0; iter < (times + 1) ; iter++) {
        jTarget.animate({ top: ((iter % 2 == 0 ? distance * Math.random() : distance * Math.random() * -1)), left: ((iter % 2 == 0 ? distance * Math.random() : distance * Math.random() * -1)) }, interval);
    }
    return jTarget.animate({ top: 0 , left: 0 }, interval);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Position had to be absolute on my side, so I changed it to:

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function(interval, distance, times) {
  interval = typeof interval == "undefined" ? 100 : interval;
  distance = typeof distance == "undefined" ? 10 : distance;
  times = typeof times == "undefined" ? 3 : times;
  var jTarget = $(this);
  for (var iter=0;iter<(times+1);iter++) {
    jTarget.animate({ 'padding-left': ((iter%2==0 ? distance : distance*-1))}, interval);
  }
  return jTarget.animate({ 'padding-left': 0 } ,interval);
}
```