# What is the true way of adding callback functionality to custom JQuery Animation?

Tags: jquery, animation, callback, effect, shake

i've found a shake effect in stackoverflow question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4399005/implementing-jquerys-shake-effect-with-animate/4399433#4399433))

Code is like below;

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function(intShakes, intDistance, intDuration) {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).css("position","relative"); 
        for (var x=1; x<=intShakes; x++) {
        $(this).animate({left:(intDistance*-1)}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)))
    .animate({left:intDistance}, ((intDuration/intShakes)/2))
    .animate({left:0}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)));
    }
  });
return this;
};
```

but i need a way to add a callback function (or any other simple way) for chaging border color of shaking element before the effect and toggle to orginal color after animation complate.
 I tried like below but no chance (border is turning original color immediately)

```
jQuery.fn.shake = function(intShakes, intDistance, intDuration,callback) {
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).css("position","relative"); 
        for (var x=1; x<=intShakes; x++) {
        $(this).animate({left:(intDistance*-1)}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)))
    .animate({left:intDistance}, ((intDuration/intShakes)/2))
    .animate({left:0}, (((intDuration/intShakes)/4)));
    }
  });
if(callback) callback();
return this;
};
```

and call like this

```
$elem.css('borderColor','red');
$elem.shake(3,5,500,function(){
$elem.css('borderColor','#a6caf0');})
```

You can find a JSFiddle Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/AlpDmr/f96ff/).(If you cancel callback function in fiddle you'll see that borders become red correctly but callback fails.)
Thaks right now...

Comment: Check out the "Tidy up" button in jsFiddle...

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Where? I've never heard of that.

Comment: @JaredFarrish In jsFiddle in the upper toolbar... it's on of the buttons.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Holy cow, that's awesome. I was actually (he he) looking at Firebug. I was like, Where???

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I did but code is looks tidy already..

Comment: @Alpert - Not really: http://jsfiddle.net/f96ff/1/

Comment: @Alper Are you kidding me? The indentation in your demo is broken...

Comment: @Alper Have you tried the solution proposed by the accepted answer in that other question (that `jquery.effects.shake.js` script)?

Comment: Ok i have problem about Js Fiddle (i mean i am not kidding), i still see the nicely indented code block, even after pressing Tidy Up several times, i updated. How it is now?

Comment: @Šime Vidas - I didn't tried because i don't want to include new file in my project and this code snippet works well. And i think this is one of the way of learning ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$.fn.shake = function ( times, distance, duration, callback ) {
    return this.css({ position: 'relative' }).each( function () {            
        for ( var i = 0, t = duration / times; i < times; i+= 1 ) {
            $( this ).
                animate({ left: -distance }, t / 3 ).
                animate({ left:  distance }, t / 3 ).
                animate({ left:         0 }, t / 4 );
        }

        $( this ).show( callback );
    });
};
```

And then...

```
$( button ).click( function () {
    $( field ).addClass( 'shaking' ).shake( 5, 10, 500, function () {
        $( this ).removeClass( 'shaking' );
    });
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/f96ff/8/

A timer is not needed. You just add the `callback` function to the effects queue via the (neutral) `.show()` method. This ensures that the `callback` is invoked only *after* all the animations (from the queue) have finished.

Additionally, I recommend a CSS class for the "shaking" state:

```
.shaking { border-color: red; }
```

Also, notice that I significantly refactored the code for `$.fn.shake`. I recommend you to take a few minutes of your time to analyze how I improved the code.

Comment: @alper - The reason I didn't upvote your accepted answer was because I instinctively didn't accept the `timeout` method. I hope you see this answer.

Comment: Wow it looks pretty, as i mentioned before i'am trying to learn in more depth.. Thanks for your pure (perfect) JQuery solution.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a timeout, you cant just call the callback directly because the animate function of jquery is async. So it will execute the callback directly. What can be done is set a timeout to the time of the total animation.

You also can't just use the callback of the animate function of jQuery because you are using multiple.

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/f96ff/2/

Comment: Šime Vidas fund a better way to do it with pure JQuery, but thanks again for your rapid and working answer.