# How to create a wiggle effect on a image when hovering

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a wiggle effect on a few images on my homepage!

I want to accomplish this when I hoved the mouse over the image. I have the following html:

> ```
> <div id="Background">
> <br /><br />
>     <div class="Menu">
>        <div>
>        <button class ="ButtonClass">Activities</button>
>        <button class ="ButtonClass">Offers</button>
>        <button class ="ButtonClass">Skills</button>
>        </div>
>     </div>
>     <div id="Content">
>     <h1>Activities</h1>
>
>     <div id ="newsSection">
>
>
>      <h4>
>                 <span class="subhead">Satan Kommer ej</span></h4>
>             <p>
>                !</p>
>             <h4>
>                 <span class="subhead">Börjar den 14 December!</span></h4>
>             <p>
>            </p>
>             <h4>
>                 <span class="subhead">2012 top </span></h4>
>
>                <table id="theList">
>                   <thead>
>                   <tr>
>                       <th>Namn</th>
>                       <th>has</th>
>                   </tr>
>                   </thead>
>                   <tbody>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Henrik</td>
>                       <td>500k</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Erik</td>
>                       <td>450k</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Samer</td>
>                       <td>400K</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Jakob</td>
>                       <td>350K</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Pontus</td>
>                       <td>300k</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Peder</td>
>                       <td>250K</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Chefen</td>
>                       <td>200K</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Johan</td>
>                       <td>150K</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Tania</td>
>                       <td>100K</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   <tr>
>                       <td>Perica</td>
>                       <td>54K</td>
>                   </tr>
>                   </tbody>
>                 </table>   
>
>     </div>
>     <br />
>     <h5>peps:</h5>    
>
>     <div id="Consultants">
>
>      <img src="/images/erik.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" float ="left" />
>      <img src="/images/PONY.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" float ="left" />
>      <img src="/images/peder.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" float ="left" />
>      <img src="/images/sael.jpg" alt="" width="70" height="70" float ="left" />
>
>
>
>
>     </div>
>
>     </div> 
>     </div>
>     <br />
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

I have the following jquery code:

```
$(function () {


  $("#Consultants img").hover(wiggle, wiggle);


    function wiggle(evt) {
    $(this).wiggle()

    };
};
```

When I add the code and press the "code sample" button it did not seem to work so I had to have it like this sorry.

My problem is that I have tried several solutions online but could not make them work so after a few hours of trying I decided to ask for help.

the jquery code might not be 100% correct but it is more of a code sample so that you can understand what I am trying to do. I hope you can fill in the rest.

Thanks!

Comment: Simply put: there's no `$.wiggle()` function (unless you define it or import a plugin which does that). You'll need to define a [custom animation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to do the wiggling.

Comment: Are you using a wiggle plugin?

Comment: I am aware of that there is not wiggle() function in the jquery library. As i mentioned at the end of the question it is not correct it is a sample of code so that the kind genious who has greater knowledge than me can help me do this. I have tried several ways of solving this and i could not make it work and in many cases i did not even understand what they did. Thats why i left it like this.

If someone has the time i need a answer that involves an entire aniimated plugin (with comments). I don´t want to come off as lazy but im really frustruated, ive been at this for several hours

Comment: @Ra3IDeN next time to avoid confustion put a comment in your code along the lines of `/*This is where I'm stuck*/` so that we know that this is where you need help\code and aren't left wondering if you are using a plug in or not.

Comment: Try this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4399433/934565

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok since you're frustrated, just use this [plugin](http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/jquery.wiggle/demo/):

This plugin just simple trigger the wiggle animation on click for an element such as image in your case but since you require `wiggle effect on a image when hovering` so just use [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function for example:

```
$('div#wigglewrapper img').hover(function(){
    $(this).wiggle('start');
},function(){
    $(this).wiggle('stop');
});
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Sorry if i came of as a jerk here but my head was ready to explode! thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Heres a wiggle function without a plugin. Just jquery...

```
var wiggle = function(myelement) {
  $(myelement)
    .animate({'left':(-10)+'px'},200)
    .animate({'left':(+20)+'px'},200)
    .animate({'left':(-10)+'px'},200);
 };
```

Call it like this:

```
wiggle('#myelement');
```

Comment: Editted after the downvote. This works. I tested it.

Comment: Better to have positions of -10, +10, and 0 since those are destinations and not movements.  Also, for it to be smoother, double the second duration.

Answer (score 1):

@Octopus' answer is (no longer?) working. First of all, the animations are asynchronous, so they might fire in any order, so you have to nest the subsequent animations in the `complete` callbacks, and passing `'-10px'` sets the absolute value, so you need `'-=10px'`. Also, `left` does not work on all elements (neither is `margin` universal, so you might need to experiment).

Here's my quick and dirty adaptation from Octopus' answer, use it when you need the functionality once and move on:

```
var parent = $('your-selector');

parent.animate(
    {'margin-right' : '-=5px', 'margin-left' : '+=5px'},
    200,
    function() {
        parent.animate(
            {'margin-right' : '+=10px', 'margin-left' : '-=10px'},
            100,
            function() {
                parent.animate({'margin-right' : '-=5px', 'margin-left' : '+=5px'}, 200)
            })
    })
```